# Loading PHP file using JQuery in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to load a PHP file in a DIV with JQuery using the code below:

```
jQuery(pid + " .entry-details .details-wrapper").load("http://thesitename.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/entry-details.php", {'postid': theid});
```

I have already added the code below to my theme's function.php:

```
function my_init_slider()
{
    wp_register_script( 'bpslider-script-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bpslider.js',
    array('jquery'), 1.0, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bpslider-script-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_init_slider' );
```

However, the Wordpress functions (such as get_header() and query functions) in my PHP file are not recognised, thus resulting in error 500. I've tried stripping all the code and only echo the ID that I passed, and it works. Therefore, I'm sure that the wordpress functions cause the error. I know that including wp-load.php is not a good practice, so I'm avoiding that.

Can anyone give me solution to this?

Comment: php must run on the server not the client (browser)

Comment: as i know, i think your request goes to 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' file not the complete url of the file.

Comment: Why you want to load the php file. Just clarify you want to display the `<?php bla bla...  ?>` or just **response/output** from the php file